# Can I feed SwiftKey (or other keyboard) with a large body of text to train it?

Tags: keyboard, swiftkey

I find SwiftKey to be not that great in terms of prediction regarding technical language, both in English and Polish (which seems to be trained on news articles, so double useless). Is there an easy way to train SwiftKey with a large (order of megabytes) body of text to improve its prediction accuracy? If not, are there any keyboards out there that allow it?

Theoretically one could either emulate a physical keyboard and leave it overnight or dump the text into messages so SwiftKey could read it. No idea how practical that would be.